Android Google Maps remove polygon
Not sure if there is a proper solution for this
It seems the Google Maps addPolygon returns a polygon object instantly but is added asynchronously
This is currently resulting in "irremovable polygons" in my code and resulting in doubles
eg: map.addPolygon(polygonOptions).remove() you will have a polygonObject which you can't remove (even map.clear() doesn't do the trick)
should i file a bug report or am i missing something here?
(obviously my app is not doing the add.remove())

One approach is to defer any removal to the map views message queue which in theory would be in position after any work the map did to render the circle.  Even if that succeeds, without knowing the implementation or explanation it may be a fragile approach.

This has been raised already in Google Public Issue Tracker. You can check it here.

You need to keep a handle or an array of handles to it (1/N);
this provides access to each Individual instance of polygon.
/* If there's only one: */
Polygon mPolygon = null;

/* When there are multiple: */
ArrayList<Polygon> mPolygons = new ArrayList<>();

Instance first with new Polygon(...), then store the handle, then add to map. The removal works in the opposite direction (the handles need to be maintained synchronously). Complex data-types in Java are always "call by reference", that's why one has to sometimes keep a reference.

i guess you haven't tried this out :)
it's the google map creating the polygon by calling map.addPolygon(polygonOptions) and returning the reference
if then (before the map asynchronously adds the polygon) i call remove, it seems to be broken
